# Is there a way to start vim in terminal mode?

Tags: terminal-buffer

I often find myself

1. Opening a terminal
2. Running `vim`
3. Starting a `:terminal`

Is there a way to say `vim --start-terminal` and have Vim automatically run `:terminal ++curwin` as soon as it starts?

Comment: Run a terminal emulator within vim?  ISTM that vi is turning into emacs!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you aren't literally asking for a `--start-terminal` flag :) ...but you can specify a command for Vim to run after it starts up using the `-c` flag.

So this should be as easy as

```
vim -c ':term ++curwin'
```

When I run it I am indeed in a terminal window on the shell command line and it's the only window open. Hopefully that covers what you're asking for.

Comment: Ha, no I'm not literally asking for `--start-terminal`. It was just to try to convey the idea. Thanks!